# Humans are dead is dead

Tags: bug, status-completed, captcha, broken-link

While adding [the CAPTCHA page link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/captcha) to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89557/the-human-verification-screen-showing-humans-are-dead-is-rather-distasteful), I noticed that the image on that page links to [this](http://www.jinx.com/men/shirts/video_games) - however, since [that t-shirt has been discontinued](http://www.jinx.com/men/shirts/video_games/humans_are_dead.html?catid=79), linking to the video_games page explains nothing.

This actually seems sorta appropriate...

However, it might cause a bit less confusion if the link simply pointed to [the dead t-shirt page](http://www.jinx.com/men/shirts/video_games/humans_are_dead.html?catid=79).

Yours in death,

Comment: Hah! Serves it right for being offensive.

Answer (score 1):

Do T-Shirts actually die?  It seems to me they just frayed around the edges and then are used to wax the car or polish the shoes.

I guess **Humans are dead is being used to wax my car** is not as good a title.

Comment: "But see look at the collar, see it's fraying. Golden Boy is slowly dying. Each wash is bringing him one step closer, that's what makes the T-shirts such a tragic figure."  [The Marine Biologist](http://www.seinfeldscripts.com/TheMarineBiologist.htm)